# JMeter View Results Tree - filter results

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Is there a way to filter out all entries except just one or two particular threads in JMeter View Results Tree listener?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view results tree to the thread group directly.  View Results Trees which have a thread group as their direct parent will only show requests made by that thread group.

View Results Trees can also be added directly to a HTTP Sampler.  When added directly to a sampler that tree will only show results from that specific HTTP Sampler.

[image: View Results Tree Locations]

In the image View Results Tree will record requests from both thread groups.  View Results Tree 1  will only record HTTP Request Google and HTTP Request Bing, Tree 2 will record HTTP Request MSN and Tree 3 will record HTTP Request MSN and HTTP Request Yahoo.

Be careful though, View Results Tree should only be used for debugging and should not be enabled during an actual performance test according to best practices.

Comment: Your commet doesn't answer my question how to narrow down the selection to requests from a single thread.

Comment: To do only one or two threads you would need to put the view results tree on the root of the thread group and only run said group with 1 or 2 threads.

Comment: This answer does not explain how to filter out 999 threads and display only 1 in this listener.

Comment: You would need to create 2 thread groups, the first only executing 1 thread with the View Results Tree positioned the same place as View Results Tree 1 in the image, then create another thread group executing the other 999.